# Why does forever stop?

Tags: node.js

I have been using forever with node.js. The application comes down after some time. I see that both forever and node.js are down. What could be the reason? And also there are no logs of forever/node.js. The forever command that I used is as below:

```
forever --spinSleepTime 10000 -o out.log -e error.log server.js > npm.log 2>&1 &
```

I don't see anything in npm.log.

Comment: Can you please share your applications entry point ?, try this once `forever start ./bin/www`

Comment: server.js is the one which initiates a port to listen

Comment: Just try `forever stopall` to stop any previous running scripts then run `forever start server.js` and look for any running forever process `forever list`